# Montar um Datatable ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net

Preciso de um help em como montar meu datatable dentro da minha Controller, a partir de uma busca.

Primeiro é um filtro com um OptionList que escolhe nome de base csv, por exemplo Base01.csv, Base02.csv e um campo texto Num_Cli onde colocamos um número de 5 digitos.

Depois vem meu JS ImportacaoBase.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {


FiltrarDados();
//debugger;

$('body').on('change', '#id_arquivo', function () {
    FiltrarDados();
});

$('body').on('click', '#btnFiltrar', function () {
    FiltrarDados();
});

//Botões de paginação
$('body').on('click', '.pagination li a', function () {
    FiltrarDados($(this).attr('pagina'));
});
```

});

function FiltrarDados(numeroPagina) {
    MensagemBloqueio("Carregando...");

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ImportacaoBase/Filtrar',
    data: {
        "Id_Arquivo": $('#id_arquivo').val(),
        "Num_Cli": $('#num_cli').val(),
        "NumPagina": numeroPagina
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (resultado) {
        $('#divResultadoPesquisa').slideUp("", function () {
            $('#divResultadoPesquisa').html(resultado);
            $('#divResultadoPesquisa').slideDown("");
        });

        DesbloquearPagina();
    },
    fail: function (resultado) {
        ExibirMensagem(resultado.responseText);
        DesbloquearPagina();
    }
});
```

}

Minha Controller ImportacaoBaseController.cs contém o método Filtrar

```
 public ActionResult Filtrar(int Id_Arquivo, string Num_Cli, int? NumPagina)
    {
        try
        {

            PaginacaoManualVO paginacao = new PaginacaoManualVO() { PageNumber = (NumPagina ?? 1), RowspPage = 10 };

            BaseIC baseic = new BaseIC();

            var resultado = new List<TB_Base_IC>();

            switch (Id_Arquivo)
            {
                case (int)ETipoBaseImportacao.IC:
                    resultado = baseic.ListarBase(Num_Cli, paginacao);
                    break;



                default:
                    break;
            }

            ViewBag.PaginacaoManual = paginacao;

            return PartialView("PartialResultadoPesquisa", resultado);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExibirMensagem(ex.Message, ETipoMensagem.Erro, 99);
            return PartialView("_ControleMensagem");
        }
    }
```

Este método Listar chama onde estou tentando montar a DataTable no outro método chamado ListarBase, não consigo montar a query para trazer os dados, gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de se fazer abaixo:

```
        public List<TB_Base_IC> ListarBase(string Num_Cli, PaginacaoManualVO paginacao)
    {
        using (DB_MesaPrecosContext context = new DB_MesaPrecosContext())
        {
            List<TB_Base_IC> listaBaseIc = new List<TB_Base_IC>();


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();



            paginacao.TotalRegistros = Convert.ToInt32(_recebeLogQtdLinhas.Qtd_Linhas);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Num_Cli))
            {
                listaBaseIc = context.TB_Base_IC.Where(busca => busca.NUM_CLI == Num_Cli.Trim().ToUpper())
                                                    .OrderBy(busca => busca.NUM_CLI)
                                                    .Skip(paginacao.PageNumber * paginacao.RowspPage - paginacao.RowspPage).Take(paginacao.RowspPage).ToList();
            }
            else
                listaBaseIc = context.TB_Base_IC.OrderBy(busca => busca.NUM_CLI).Skip(paginacao.PageNumber * paginacao.RowspPage - paginacao.RowspPage).Take(paginacao.RowspPage).ToList();

            return listaBaseIc;
        }
    }
```

Esta ocorrendo o erro abaixo:
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id_Arquivo' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Filtrar(Int32, System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' in 'Itau.DPE.MesaPrecos.Web.Controllers.ImportacaoBaseController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Nome do parâmetro: parameters
Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.

O método filtrar no debug traz o erro, a variável resultado vem sempre com 0, abaixo o resultado do meu PartialResultadoPesquisa:

```html
@using Empresa.DCR.Comum.Utils.Utilitarios;
@using Empresa.DCR.Comum.Utils.Enumeradores;
@using Empresa.DPE.Projeto.DAO.Enumeradores;
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data

<div class="table-responsive">
    @{
        if (Model != null)
        {
        <table id="gridSquad" class="table table-striped Exp-Table table-hover table-vcenter pad-no">

            @*//inclusao do if*@
            
            <tr class="table-tr">
                @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                {
                    <th>@col.Caption</th>
                } 
            </tr>

            @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
            { 
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        if (cell != null)
                        {
                            <td>@cell.ToString()</td>
                        }else
                        {
                            <td></td>
                        }
                    } 
                </tr>               
                       
            }
        </table>
            Html.RenderPartial("_Paginacao");
        }
        else
        {
        <table class="table table-striped Exp-Table">
            <tr class="table-tr">
                <th colspan="100%">Não houve resultados para a pesquisa. </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Não entendi direito do por que do parâmetro, obrigado.

Comment: Seria legal reformular a pergunta e se cocentrar no erro de fato... mas a mensagem é clara... você está tentando atribuir `null` para uma propriedade `Id_Arquivo` do tipo `int32` e não aceita valores nulos

Answer (score 0):

Olá novamente pessoal,

O objetivo era montar um DATATABLE de resultado segundo a escolha de um nome num optionlist do HtmlRazor, após clicar no botão filtrar, um método se encarregaria de montar um DATATABLE com uma query buscando a tabela em base SQL e paginando em tela, como abaixo:

```
public DataTable ListarBase(string Num_Cli, ref PaginacaoManualVO paginacao)
    {
        using (var con = Utilitario.RecuperaConexaoToken())
        {
            if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Open();


            //Total Linhas
            string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID_Importacao) FROM [dbo].[TABELA] WITH (NOLOCK)";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Num_Cli))
                query += string.Format(" WHERE NUM_CLI = '{0}'", Num_Cli);

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                paginacao.TotalRegistros = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());


            //Linhas
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TB_Base_IC] WITH (NOLOCK)";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Num_Cli))
                query += string.Format(" WHERE NUM_CLI = '{0}'", Num_Cli);

            query += string.Format(" ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP OFFSET {0} ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;", (paginacao.PageNumber * paginacao.RowspPage - paginacao.RowspPage));

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            adp.Fill(dt);

            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();

            return dt; 
        }
    }
```

Este método devolve para o outro método Filtrar entrando no switch case.

Obrigado.